# Is it possible to get Response Headers via sp_oamethod?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, sql-server-2014

I have a web service in SQL Server 2014. I'm using `sp_oamethod` for request to API. Now I'm getting response-code and response-body. And I need to get response header. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me to retrieve **Rate-Limit-Remaining** from the response header

```
DECLARE @responseHeader varchar(4000)

EXEC sp_OAMethod @res, 'getResponseHeader', @responseHeader OUT, 'Rate-Limit-Remaining'
PRINT 'Rate-Limit-Remaining: ' + coalesce(@responseHeader,'<null>')

EXEC sp_OAMethod @res, 'getResponseHeader', @responseHeader OUT, 'Rate-Limit-Reset'
PRINT 'Rate-Limit-Reset: ' + coalesce(@responseHeader,'<null>')

EXEC sp_OAMethod @res, 'getAllResponseHeaders', @responseHeader OUT
PRINT 'Response Headers: ' + coalesce(@responseHeader,'<null>')
```

Comment: Thanks for answers! But it did not work for me. Messages issued this
`Rate-Limit-Remaining: <null>`
`Rate-Limit-Reset: <null>`
`Response Headers: <null>`

Comment: I take my words back! **It works** just need to write it after `EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @res, 'send', NULL, @ParamsValues;` Thank you!